# Phoenix umbrella app code reloader failing after changes of compile.lock and mix.exs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm experiencing an issue with an umbrella app composed of a phoenix app and proxy app which depends upon [master_proxy](https://github.com/jesseshieh/master_proxy) (which permits to serve different sites with a single port, useful for heroku env for example).

I get this runtime error

```
** (RuntimeError) could not compile application: proxy.

You must restart your server after changing the following config or lib files:

  * redacted_path/umbrella_app_name/_build/dev/lib/proxy/.mix/compile.lock
  * mix.exs
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that phoenix will try to recompile both apps (the phoenix one and the proxy one) which is something we don't want.
To fix this you need to set up your endpoint this way using the [`reloadable_apps` setting](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.CodeReloader.html#reload!/1) :

```
config :webapp,
       WebApp.Endpoint,
       reloadable_apps: [:webapp]
```